# How can I get notified of schema changes in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

When users run migrations / alter tables I'd like to be notified.

I've tried/considered the following:

- Change data capture - I receive insert/update/delete but not alter table notifications, maybe I missed a configuration or alter isn't supported here
- trigger on schema_information
- read the WAL
- something built-in that I missed in the docs

This is for pg 15, but going back a few versions would probably be best.

Thanks

Comment: I think your only option is a [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html)  combined with [notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html)

Comment: I like the idea of a watchdog on the log files and tracing DDL in the logs